# Solr/Lucene - Custom Data Clustering

Tags: solr, lucene, cluster-analysis

Can someone please tell me if there is a way to have a custom `clustering of the data` from `solr` 'query' results? I am facing 2 issues currently:

1. The `Carrot` clustering only applies clustering to the "paged" results (i.e. in the current pagination's page results).
2. I need to have custom clustering and classify results into certain classes only (i.e. only few very specific words in the search results). Like for example "Red", "Green", "Blue" etc... and not "hello World", "Known World", "green world" etc.... -(if you know what I mean here) - Where all these words in both Do and DoNot existing in the search results.

Please tell me how to achieve this. Perhaps Carrot/clustering is not needed here and some other classifier is needed. So what to do here?

Basically, I cannot receive 1 million results, then process them via PHP-Array to classify them as per need. The classification must be done here in solr only.

Thanks

Comment: Although i dont have a direct answer it might be undefined to know that 'clustering ' around an explicitly defined set of terms is generally Called 'classification' instead of 'clustering'

Comment: As Greet pointed out it is probably Classification what you are looking for as there terms are predefined terms. Check for Mahout with Solr for classification.

Comment: @Jayendra: has anyone actually implemented Mahout with Solr? I still see a lot of presentations but no easy workaround. It looks like a project of its own....

Comment: I remember there is an Integration between Mahout and Solr, but it is more work for sure. Haven't seen it for quite some time.

Comment: I saw some presentations online on how to get it done... and it looked like rocket science :D